# Postion google sign in popup window/Redirection customisation in auth0 signin to a certain position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-signin, auth0

Is it possible to position the google sign-in(`social sign-in`) popup(powered by `auth0`) window to a certain position?

I want to either:

1)- Position it to the drawer shown in the right side in the attached image

2)- Redirect the user within the right drawer to google sign-in without changing the context in the left section of the page

How do I achieve any of the above points? Not able to find anything related to this in `auth0` implementation docs

[image: Implementation Pic]